# JQuery 1.9.1 min.js file Invalid operand to 'in' Object expected

Tags: jquery, object

first time poster and somewhat beginning developer.  Tried looking for the answer in many places but nothing specific and i really need help.

I'm trying to install an image rotator/slider (nivo) onto this site cdms.amctec.net.  The image rotator works fine in FF, but I receive the following error message in IE 9 and all other browsers in the conosole:

```
SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected *jquery.min.js, line 5 character 1203*
```

This is a script I'm pulling from Google so I'm not sure it's a bug or if I'm not calling it right on my end with a patch or something.

Can anybody help me figure out a solution and make this work for non-FF browsers?

Thanks, Mike

---

Implementation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: "boxRain", // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices: 15, // For slice animations
    boxCols: 8, // For box animations
    boxRows: 4, // For box animations
    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 7000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
    controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false // Force manual transitions
   /* prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
    randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
    beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded */
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's not much to go on. Grab the non-minified jquery.js file and link to it instead while developing. Then you can at least see more about the error.

Comment: The problem is probably not in the jquery file. It just can't perform an operation because of some wrong parameters. You should share some implementation code, so we can help.

Comment: Try with jQuery 1.7.1. I can't find any statement in nivoSlider documentation which says it supports jQuery 1.9.

Comment: BTW the error is most probably caused in `vendorPropName` function in jQuery 1.9.1 unminified source on line 6643 or line 6654. That's why it would work on some browsers, but not on others.

Comment: Ok, tried v. 1.7.1 with no change and now threw in a local copy of non-min Jquery 1.9.1.  Here is the new error (which happens to be on line 6646, char 2  // shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed //  if ( name in style ) {
  return name;

Comment: Link to my copy:  http://cdms.amctec.net/templates/cdms/js/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Ok after banging my head and trying to figure out code, I discovered that there was a trivial conflict error with Joomla's system mootools and jquery.  After subbing out the $ in my code to $jQuery.noConflict() it worked like a charm.  Sorry everyone!

Comment: @MikeEstes, please add your solution as an answer. You can answer your own questions.